# Windows doesn't save the -turn off the display- time

Tags: windows-7, display-settings

I remember setting once the -turn off the display- to 1 minute.

Ever since, I've been trying to change that to 10 or 5 minutes and the system actually *does* keep this change... until I reboot or shutdown the computer (then it sets back to 1 minute).

Never happened this to me before. Is there a way to make it permanent?

[image]

Comment: Are you performing a clean restart? Or are you shutting it down by force?

Comment: I always do a clean restart.

Comment: No one knows? I still have the problem.